# Multithreading in Titan throws exception

Tags: java, titan

I am creating a vertices in Titan with multiple threads.
Here's my code

Trying to connect to Titan, Specifying the schema and then Adding vertices.

```
g = TitanFactory.open("/conf/titan-cassandra.properties");
TitanManagement mgmt = g.getManagementSystem();
final PropertyKey userid = mgmt.makePropertyKey("userid").dataType(Integer.class).make();
TitanGraphIndex namei = mgmt.buildIndex("userid",Vertex.class).addKey(userid).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.setConsistency(namei, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
mgmt.commit();
```

Then I'm calling a function to Add Vertex

Multiple threads accessing function Add Vertex which takes input parameter - randomly generated unique numbers (entityPK)

```
tx1 = g.newTransaction();
Vertex user_ver = tx1.addVertexWithLabel("user");
user_ver.setProperty("userid",entityPK);
//Adding other properties for vertex
tx1.commit();`
```

I read that the exception that is thrown is because of not specifying the LOCK. But even after specifying LOCK, exception is thrown.

com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not commit transaction due to exception during persistence

Answer (score 0):

If this code:

```
tx1 = g.newTransaction();
Vertex user_ver = tx1.addVertexWithLabel("user");
user_ver.setProperty("userid",entityPK);
//Adding other properties for vertex
tx1.commit();
```

is inside of your `addVertex` function and multiple threads are calling `addVertex`, I don't think you're using `newTransaction` quite right.  That creates what is referred to as a "threaded transaction".  A threaded transaction is one where multiple threads act on the SAME transaction.  In your usage, each thread is creating its own DIFFERENT transaction.  Given what you've described, I would say that the correct approach would be to make `addVertex` be:

```
Vertex user_ver = g.addVertexWithLabel("user");
user_ver.setProperty("userid",entityPK);
//Adding other properties for vertex
g.commit();
```

I would also consider dropping locking (unless you need it).